# How to represent the following math in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

I want to know how to express the following (complicated) math equations in LaTeX.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your query is asking for a lot of fairly diverse types of code, and it has a strong "do-this-for-me-even-though-I'm-not-showing-any-research-effort" flavor. As it stands, your posting is very broad and may be of little or no interest for other users of this site. Please consider (a) reading an introduction to TeX and LaTeX -- this site contains several postings on such material -- and (b) editing your question (and, likely, posting additional questions) so that real question is being asked per posting. Most of the math expressions you've listed are quite basic, by the way.

Comment: @Mico, this is also a way to learn latex.

Comment: Actually, I doubt very much that one can *learn* LaTeX via the "do-this-for-me-command" approach. It's true that many postings that exhibit precisely this approach may be found on this site, and it's also true that many of these postings get closed for being too broad.

Comment: @user3761566 I think that Mico is right. Stackexchange is about helping people, not doing their work for them. Your question is very basic. As a new user you are presented for the guidelines on this website. Before you post, you should a) have read a LaTeX beginner manual b) googled your problem c) post an minimal example. You could have asked about a special problem, like "how to make a sigma". But actually, you should know how to, after reading a beginner manual/or using google. A lot of persons are very helpful here: but you should have tried yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \[ A \in R^{M \times K_{0,}} \]

    \[ u = [u_1,\dots,u_{K_0}]^T \]

    \[ \min\sum^{K_0}_{i=1}(u_i+v_i), \text{ s.t. } [A,-A][u^T,v^T]^T = y, u \geq 0, v \geq 0, \]

    \[ \mathit{Ind}^{(n)}_+ \text{ and } \mathit{Ind}^{(n)}_- \]

    \[ \mathit{IND}^+_k = \underset{n}{\bigcup}\mathit{Ind}^{(n)}_+, \quad  \mathit{IND}^-_k = \underset{n}{\bigcup}\mathit{Ind}^{(n)}_-\]

    \[ f_\sigma(t) \overset{\Delta}{=} \exp\left(\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \]

    \[ \|s\|^0_0 \approx n - F_\sigma(s) \text{ for small } \sigma \]

    \[ \textstyle F_\sigma(s) = \sum_{i=1}^nf_\sigma(s_1) \]

    \[ \begin{array}{c}
            \max\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0} F_\sigma(s) \\
            \text{s.t. } y = \text{As}
        \end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd prefer `\mathit` to `\textit`.

Comment: @egreg I changed it.

Comment: With `\textit` other font attributes might be kept (try it in a boldface context).